# How to detect *any* DOM modification what so ever

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, javascript-objects, dom-events

I'm wondering how to listen to ANY change in the DOM what so ever. For example:

- A class has been added to something? I want to catch that and process stuff.
- A new element has been injected? I want to catch that and process stuff.

Literally any DOM edit. I don't need to know what the edit was exactly, just that it has been edited.

Non of the other questions regarding DOM changes in Stackoverflow have a solution for detecting changes in data-attributes or simple element properties for example. Only classes or nodes being inserted / removed.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect changes in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom)

Comment: Non of the other links have a solution for detecting changes in data-attributes or simple element properties for example. Only classes or nodes being inserted / removed.

Comment: There's possibly a third-party application that could provide assistance - have you considered this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: consider using `Proxy`, or you can modify all methods of the `window.document` (maybe you'll need to use `Object.defineProperty`) like wrapping a function outside those methods. Sounds a bit dirty, but it should work.

Comment: @user3586610 The duplicate question linked to mentions MutationObserver, which is what you probably should be using.  If you set `attributes: true`, you'll get those attribute changes.